Issues with the useBalance wagmi hook
I am using useBalance wagmi hook in a react ts projects.
the useBalance hook is working fine when wallet is connected but does not work when i disconnect my wallet.
i checked passing a valid address but behavior is same
const balanceOfVault = useBalance({
    address: "0x5650Fa9E13963C6663279c0E36F064cf37831EEF",
    query: {
      enabled: VaultCAT !== undefined,
    },
  });

